# Why is the film called "Saving Mr. Banks"?

Tags: title, saving-mr.-banks

I saw the movie, Mr. Banks is a character in the "Mary Poppins" story.

But the whole plot does not match the title, Helen Goff was heavily influenced by her father "Travers Robert Goff". She wants Mary Poppins to be a non-animated film.

Then why is the title "Saving Mr. Banks"?

Comment: *"*[Seeing how troubled Travers was](http://rw360.org/2014/01/05/saving-mr-banks/) over the negative depiction of Mr. Banks (but not yet understanding his connection to her father), the Disney team softened his character and revised the ending of the movie. They wrote a new song that deeply moved Travers and enabled her to imagine both Mr. Banks and her father as having been saved from their lonely, self-destructive lives (thus the title, Saving Mr. Banks).*"

Comment: @Richard - sounds like an answer to me rather than a comment, I'd upvote it as it was going to be my answer

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager - Having never seen the film and having done only 30 seconds of googling to see if the answer was obvious (it was), I don't feel overly qualified to answer. If you want to use the quote, go ahead/

Comment: Hey, googling the answer (if it's right) is nothing to be ashamed of!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The movie wants us to believe that the deal between Disney and Travers came to be because, despite their cultural differences, both recognized one another as having daddy issues too.

In that vein, Mary Poppins is there to save the *father* more than the children, thus leading to her **saving Mr. Banks** – and possibly the memory that the two protagonists have of their fathers' lives as well.